# Pulseaudio, audio stuttering and rtkit spam

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

Here is my problem: no matter the Linux distro I try on my computer, I am facing a certain problem. Basically, the audio is stuttering. Sometimes it will be fine for a few minutes, sometimes it will stutter 3 times in 30 seconds.
Here is what I could gather so far:

- It would appear the problem is due to a kind of constant reconnection of the Built-in Audio entry. When looking at `pavucontrol`, in the Configuration tab, I can change the Built-in Audio profile, and it will always be set back to Analog Stereo Output after some time (after these "reconnection"
- On Ubuntu 16.04, I found a workaround. With `hdajackretask`, I would at each boot set the rear output line out as disconnected, and the front one as "headphones" (this is a desktop computer, not a laptop). After doing that, everything would be fine. However, the boot override never worked, and I always had to do it. It wasn't much pain since it's relatively quick, and it allows me to actually use my computer.
- Today, I reinstalled said computer. I tried both Manjaro 20.2 and Ubuntu 20.04. Both showed the same problem. The thing is, I can't use the same trick as in 16.04. `hdajackretask` will always tell me that the device is busy, so I can't override the entry, and if I manage to completely kill `pulseaudio` (without respawn) to apply the settings, only the dummy output will remain, which means I have no audio in that case. However, I could do it in the live Ubuntu CD
- I have found a new thing: if I check `journalctl`, doing it in live `(journalctl -f`) allows me to see that each time the Built-in Audio is "reconnected", i have several lines like these that show up. The process of 1909 is `pulseaudio`:

```
Dez 21 18:09:01 thomas-ubudesk rtkit-daemon[943]: Successfully made thread 3912 of process 1909 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5. 
Dez 21 18:09:01 thomas-ubudesk rtkit-daemon[943]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users. 
Dez 21 18:09:02 thomas-ubudesk rtkit-daemon[943]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 1 users. 
Dez 21 18:09:02 thomas-ubudesk rtkit-daemon[943]: Successfully made thread 3913 of process 1909 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Dez 21 18:09:02 thomas-ubudesk rtkit-daemon[943]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
```

Also, I dual boot with windows, and there are no audio problems there.
So my guess is that for some reasons, the `pulseaudio` process priority is kind of reset, which leads to the observed behaviour.
Do you have an idea as to what I could do? Thanks in advance, and don't hesitate to ask for more details.

PS: Here is a longer (but not especially more informative) part of my `journalctl`: https://pastebin.pl/view/757971d1